# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'profilePic'

Tags: python, django

I have the following in my models.py

```
profilePic = models.OneToOneField(Document, default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and in my views.py

```
loggedinanon = Anon.objects.get_or_create(username1=loggedinuser)

newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
                newdoc.save()
                loggedinanon.profilePic = newdoc
```

I can't tell what the code should be to allow the document to be saved as part of the anon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the code to

```
loggedinanon, created = Anon.objects.get_or_create(username1=loggedinuser)
```

because get_or_create returns a tuple of (instance, created)

Answer (score 0):

get_or_create function, return a tuple: (object, create) 
-object is the instance of Anon.objects.get_or_create(username1=loggedinuser)
-create is a boolean (true if object created or false if object get)

So you can try:

```
loggedinanon, creation= Anon.objects.get_or_create(username1=loggedinuser)
newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
newdoc.save()
loggedinanon.profilePic = newdoc
```

I have a doubt regarding the last line:
loggedinanon.profilePic = newdoc

I think you should have more something like:

objectName=ClassName.update(userName=loggedinanon,default={'profilePic':newdoc})

Depending of relationships of your model. Django tutorial is quite long to read but really needful
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/